# i want to make a loop that's simulate F keys to DX9 GAME

Tags: c#

i want to make a loop that's simulate F keys to DX9 GAME

and that is my code

```
  static void Example1(Keys k, Process Proces)
        {
            const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
            const uint WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
            IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(Proces.MainWindowHandle,
            new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);
            PostMessage(child, WM_KEYDOWN, ((IntPtr)k), ((IntPtr)0));
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            PostMessage(child, WM_KEYUP, ((IntPtr)0), ((IntPtr)0));
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tt = new Thread(Example2);
            tt.IsBackground = true;
            if (isRunning)
            {
                isRunning = false;
            }
            else
            {
                isRunning = true;
                tt.Start();
            }
        }
        void Example2()
        {
            Process[] notepads = Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(@"D:\Games\tahes\Env_DX9\Conquer.exe"));
            foreach (Process process in notepads)
            {
                for (; ; )
                {
                    do
                    {
                        while (!isRunning)
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        }
                        if (checkBox1.Checked) Example1(Keys.A, process);
                    } while (!checkBox2.Checked);
                    Example1(Keys.B, process); Application.DoEvents();
                }

            }

        }
```

i don't want to use sendkeys(); and SetForegroundWindow(); bec it brings the game in the front and i want to make it for more than 1 tap